# how to authenticate correctly to Google Cloud Source Repositoriess with sdk

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

I've followed the steps provided by [Google Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/) in [source.cloud.google.com](http://source.cloud.google.com)

1. gcloud init && git config --global credential.https://source.developers.google.com.helper gcloud.cmd
2. git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/[Project-id]/path
3. git push --all google

But I get the error:
    invalid authentication credentials

I'ts frustrating following those steps and not able to accomplish the task

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did follow these step for [adding repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes), and it work fine.

In some cases, you might not have access to the Cloud SDK. For example, you might work on a build server that does not have access to these tools. In these situations, you can manually generate static credentials.

Navigate to the [repository page](https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/repo?_ga=2.97513177.-790869494.1522693491).

Locate the repository and click Clone.

Change the preferred authentication method to manually generated credentials.

Follow the instructions to use the generated credentials.

Comment: Yes I did that and it worked :D, actually the account I tried to access it's the owner(me), so i don't kno why it does not work

Answer (score 3):

Do the following steps below- It worked for me

[image]

You will be getting new generated authentication credentials. You need to `copy` that and `paste` in your `cmd`. It will work perfectly then.